# .Net SDK installation on ARM64 ubuntu instance

Tags: .net, arm64

I am trying to install .Net SDK 6.0 Package on Graviton based instance but unable to do so.

While checking
dotnet --version
Error- dotnet: command not found

I refer below links-

https://github.com/aws/aws-graviton-getting-started/blob/main/dotnet.md

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMlyZI9NhFw

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#apt-troubleshooting

Are there any dependencies required to install .Net on ARM64? On Intel or AMD processor I am able to live the .Net Project. But not able to just install .Net on ARM64 processor.

Please help

Comment: make sure the `dotnet` binary is on your path

Comment: Yes. It is on same path.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for it.

I have refer below link to install .Net on graviton based server.

**https://gist.github.com/richlander/467813274cea8abc624553ee72b28213**

This link contain latest package of .net In my case I was looking for .Net 5.0

so I use below package download link

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d4b71fac-a2fd-4516-ac58-100fb09d796a/e79d6c2a8040b59bf49c0d167ae70a7b/dotnet-sdk-5.0.408-linux-arm64.tar.gz

Then refer config commands mentioned in GitHub Link above.

It works for me!

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much. (https://gist.github.com/richlander/467813274cea8abc624553ee72b28213)